# How i can concat one date with a string when i pass a property to a component with a pipe?

Tags: angular

I'm using one component of kendoUi that i need to pass in the property [title] my variable `local.localNome` `(string)` and local.LocalDataCadastro `(Date with a pipe)`

I try something like:

```
<kendo-panelbar-item *ngFor="let local of locaisList" [title]="local.LocalCadastroData | date + local.LocalNome">
```

But this way i receive:

> Unexpected token '+' at column 32 in [local.LocalCadastroData | date +
>   local.LocalNome]

How i can use my two variables in the `[title]` property with a `pipe` date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parentheses.

```
<kendo-panelbar-item *ngFor="let local of locaisList"
    [title]="(local.LocalCadastroData | date) + local.LocalNome">
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting date and local.LocalNome in brackets so that it executes it as JS.

```
<kendo-panelbar-item *ngFor="let local of locaisList" [title]="local.LocalCadastroData | {{date + local.LocalNome}}">
```

Comment: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `local.LocalCadastroData | date` into the parentheses before the concatenation.
Like so:

```html
<kendo-panelbar-item *ngFor="let local of locaisList" [title]="(local.LocalCadastroData | date) + local.LocalNome">
```

---

It would be better and more readable to add a formatting function in your component and pass in the local:
Template:

```html
<kendo-panelbar-item *ngFor="let local of locaisList" [title]="getTitle(local)">
```

Component:

```js
@Component({})
export class YourComponent {
  getTitle(local) {
    return formatDate(local.LocalCadastroData) + local.LocalNome;
  }

  private formatDate(date: Date) {
    // Format the date using custom code / existing libraries like moment.js
    return date.toDateString();
  }
}
```